# shortcut for changing how files are organised in file explorer

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, file-shortcut

configuring some macros inside of Logitech G hub, I'm setting them up for each application. I was going through the shortcuts in file explorer and assigning them to hotkeys, although cant work out if there is a shortcut to change how files are organised.

Anyone know the shortcut for that?

Thanks in advance,
Tom

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> … <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>9</kbd> to switch between layouts.

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + mouse scroll wheel to zoom; this will also switch between layouts automatically after the zoom limit for the current layout has been reached.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can get is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, then <kbd>L</kbd> to focus the layout panel. Then you need to use the cursor keys to navigate around the layout pane. If you talking about sorting, then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, then <kbd>O</kbd>

Comment: Thanks that's very useful. I hadn't thought of using the alt key when creating macros.